# Static maps upgrade cannot add controls and directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

In my old google static maps a control appeared giving the user the option to zoom pan etc and display my main address which I had a marker set to view direction search nearby etc.

I am checking the developer guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1 and the upgrade guide hand am not finding how to add that into my new static map.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Its a very basic code  an example would be http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.897096,-77.036545&zoom=13&markers=6401+C1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+Washington+D.C.&size=870x470&sensor=false

Sorry it won't let me include my html because I don't have the reputation to post images

Comment: What did you old "static map" look like?  Doesn't sound like a static map to me...

Comment: Its actually not my code I am upgrading someone elses code.  I'm new to google maps and working on the v2 to v3 upgrade at the office.  
Essentially it was on old link in an iframe to embed a map on the page using &embed without javascript on a page vs the rest of our code base which is using js to dynamically load pages.  I've already learned I need to use an img instead of the iframe.

If static maps doesn't allow this functionality is there a better way besides a regular js implementation to embed a map on a page.

Comment: I still don't understand, I don't see any controls or link on the image you posted.  Or was that in the HTML?  You can post the HTML as "code".

Comment: @geocodezip Its quite likely I am doing something pretty silly [code]<div id="map">
                      <img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.897096,-77.036545&zoom=13&markers=6401+C1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+Washington+D.C.&size=870x470&sensor=false"></> 
                    </div>[code]

Following the old code I didn't see anything to add a control in the static map. I'm assuming there is something I need to add to call a control or add in the display of the address etc in addition to the marker. I am just not seeing it in the documentation.

Comment: @geocodezip I see for the javascript api the controls https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls documentation.  Its just the old code displayed it without the need to use javascript.

Comment: No it didn't (I suppose I could be wrong, I don't use static maps that much, but the point of static maps is just that, they are static, no controls), that is what I don't understand.  Did you have an embedded google map?